# Webdriver is Unable to find element in IE 11 using Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I am new to Selenium Web driver.
I have to automate a Test Case in Internet Explorer-11. At first, I was getting the certificate error which i handled using the following code :

```
driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");
```

*but, when i try to execute the following line:*

```
driver.findElement(By.name("IDToken1")).sendKeys(abc);
```

*i am getting the following exception:*

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with name == IDToken1 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

**There is no IFrame in the page and neither the element is hidden.I have tried using explicit waits, but nothing is working out.**

Can any one Please help me.

Comment: can you please share your whole webdriver code? with question? Also share your html code.

Comment: try with xpath, you can retrieve it with firebug for example (right click on the element):         WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("the result of the xpath from firebug"));

Comment: I tried using xpath ,id and name , the problem remains the same. Also , the set of code works fine with Firefox and Chrome

Comment: `System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "d://frameworkJars//IEDriverServer_x64_2.44.0//IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver =  new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(AutomationConstants.ApplicationURL);
driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='IDToken1']")).sendKeys("abc");
driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken2")).sendKeys("12345");
driver.findElement(By.name("Login.Submit")).click();`

Comment: Any public URL where we can replicate this issue, that you are facing?

Comment: we can test on "google.com" . The problem remains the same.